# Google Map API V2 Map Is Not Visible

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I tried a lot of things which to fix it but, I still can't see the map. I'm sure that my `ApiKey` is `true` and `Google Maps Android Api v2` is active.

If I try it on emulator, it crashes. But if I try it on a real device it works, but i can't see the map, only blank plain.

My LogCat

```
10-04 21:46:35.712: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1540): Google Play Store is missing.
10-04 21:46:35.722: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1540): Google Play Store is missing.
10-04 21:46:35.763: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1540): Google Play Store is missing.
10-04 21:46:35.822: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1540): Google Play Store is missing.
10-04 21:46:35.822: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1540): Google Play Store is missing.
10-04 21:46:35.902: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1540): Google Play Store is missing.
10-04 21:46:35.902: D/AndroidRuntime(1540): Shutting down VM
10-04 21:46:35.902: W/dalvikvm(1540): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
10-04 21:46:35.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1540): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-04 21:46:35.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1540): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.tekguc.touregsys.googlemapsandroidv2/info.tekguc.touregsys.googlemapsandroidv2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-04 21:46:35.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
10-04 21:46:35.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-04 21:46:35.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-04 21:46:35.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-04 21:46:35.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-04 21:46:35.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-04 21:46:35.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-04 21:46:35.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-04 21:46:35.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-04 21:46:35.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-04 21:46:35.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-04 21:46:35.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-04 21:46:35.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1540): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-04 21:46:35.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at info.tekguc.touregsys.googlemapsandroidv2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
10-04 21:46:35.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-04 21:46:35.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-04 21:46:35.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
10-04 21:46:35.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     ... 11 more
10-04 21:46:39.262: I/Process(1540): Sending signal. PID: 1540 SIG: 9
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    
android:layout_width="match_parent"    
android:layout_height="match_parent"    
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"    
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"    
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"    
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"    
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<TextView        
android:layout_width="wrap_content"        
android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
android:text="@string/hello_world" />
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"     
        android:layout_width="match_parent"        
        android:layout_height="match_parent"        
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package info.tekguc.touregsys.googlemapsandroidv2;

import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.view.Menu; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions; 
public class MainActivity extends Activity {     
private GoogleMap mMap;         
@Override     
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {         
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);             
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();         
mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);         
final LatLng CIU = new LatLng(35.21843892856462, 33.41662287712097);         
Marker ciu = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()                                   
.position(CIU).title("My Office"));     
}     
@Override     
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {         
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.         
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);         
return true;     } }
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.tekguc.touregsys.googlemapsandroidv2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

        <permission
        android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
          <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="i wrote my api key here"/>
        <activity
            android:name="info.tekguc.touregsys.googlemapsandroidv2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the API Key is generated for debugging purposes only, ensure that your device executes the debug version of the application.

Comment: In Eclipse, Windows->Preferences->Android->Build is that true way to take my SHA1 ?

Comment: If you have used `debug.keystore` to generate your SHA1, the map will only work for a debug version of your app. See this[link]http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Answer (score 0):

make sure you installed google play services. you can follow this tutorial http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/google-maps-in-android-application-with-new-google-maps-android-api-v2-using-supportmapfragment/

Answer (score 0):

You are using Activity (not FragmentActivity) with SupportMapFragment, and I doubt that will work. Which version of android target are you using? before android 4 you must inckude compatibility library too. If you are in debug you have to generate key from debug keystore signature that is the default eclipse use, inside eclipse android settings you fine the debug keystore location,

Comment: im using version 4.1.2 on my device so i don't think thats about using SupportMapFragment.