# Android Google Maps API v2 not loading maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

Good morning, i'm having an issue with the android Google Maps Api v2, it doesn't load the maps.
I'm using SupportMapFragment, and it is placed inside a drawer nav fragment.
All the authentication is right, already checked the permissions a million times too and it still the same.
I'm posting some code and an image of the result in the emulator that was already tested in a device:

```
CreateFragment.class

    GoogleMap mMap;
    ImageButton create;
    Geocoder geoCoder;
    int radius;
    Double latitude;
    Double longitude;
    LatLng latLong;



        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create, container, false);
//          create = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.create);
//          create.setOnClickListener(Handler);
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));

            return rootView;
        }
```

fragment_create.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#efece3" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment">
         </fragment>


        <!--<ImageButton-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/create"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="65dp"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="65dp"-->
            <!--android:scaleType="fitXY"-->
            <!--android:src="@drawable/ic_new"-->
            <!--android:background="#00000000"-->
            <!--android:layout_gravity="center"/>-->




</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.myspots"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launche_small"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.android.myspots.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.android.myspots.CreateSpot"
            android:label="@string/createTitle" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.android.myspots.SpotShow"
            android:label="@string/showTitle" >
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name="com.android.myspots.CreateNotification"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_create_notification" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyC-8L-x21WRj1zjhmBXn9FKRdD0IvHO2yI" />

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

</manifest>
```

[image: The result]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Map API v2 is not showing Map on device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717273/google-map-api-v2-is-not-showing-map-on-device)

Comment: do you have meta-data for map key in manifest?

Comment: i checked that link answers and none of them resolve my issue.
ill post manifest...

Answer (score 1):

If the API Key is generated for debugging purposes only, ensure that your device executes the debug version of the application. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191422/google-map-api-v2-map-is-not-visible/19191964#19191964)

Comment: 87:9E:F4:32:7F:11:42:B2:D0:65:6C:06:75:37:66:AB:6C:BF:D7:8A;com.android.myspots
I made a key on Google Console for this Fingerprint and it still the same

Comment: Ok. Did you chek if its for debubug version? How do you generate de API key?

Comment: 1. cd C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_43\bin                                         || 2. keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\ Bruno\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android || note: i'm using Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

I personally had that problem once, seems my keytool wasnt working that great. I know that eclipse has a function that shows your SHA1, which was different than the keytool one(and working). It's at Window>Preferences>Android>Build. Don't know where to find it in Android Studio though, but it's probably in there somewhere.

Hope this answer doesn't come too late.